# Table cell truncation based on width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which has multiple cells in it. I need to truncate the cell with content in it.

I have used CSS ellipsis to achieve this and it works fine.

Now the problem is, as we know css ellipsis is not compatible with IE7 so I need to get it worked for IE7.

Can y ou please help with any javascript solution for this.

Thanks!!

Here is my current solution

```
td{
  background:#cccc33;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pohagafajodu/5/)**

*Re size the browser width to see the ellipsis*

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var str = 'Hello world', out;

if(str.length > 2) {
  out = str.substring(0, 2).concat('...');
}
```

This would result in He...
You could also use something like modernizr to detect if text-overflow is supported to decide use JS or css

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Amin52J/syj4jjmd/2/)**

```
$('td').each(function(){
    $(this).data('firstText',$(this).html());
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    var width,
        allowedChar,
        maxChar;
    $('td').each(function(){
        if($(this).width()<=38){
            var value=$(this).html();
            $('td:last').after('<td class="test">a</td>');
            $('.test').css('width','auto');
            width=$('.test').width();
            $('.test').remove();
            maxChar=Math.floor(20/width);
            if($(this).html().length>maxChar+3){
                allowedChar=Math.floor($(this).width()/width);
                allowedChar-=3;
                $(this).html($(this).html().substring(0, allowedChar).concat('...'));
            }
        }
        else{
            $(this).html($(this).data('firstText'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is that class="test" ?? ANd this is how it works when there are less cells. I want it to be normal and only when it reached the cell width 20px text in it should get truncated.

Comment: to get the size of one letter, depending on the font size

Comment: I need to calculate the cell width not text width. Please check my updated demo for clear picture. Only when browser size decreases, the cell width reached 20px then the truncation should happen. Thank you.

Comment: check out the updated answer, resize to see the outcome!

Comment: this is all jQuery based, nothing will keep it from being cross-browser! there might be something else going on